# debian and apache2 install

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, installation, apt

I just logged in to my newly purchased VPS server that used debian and tried to install apache2, here what happens as a root:

```
vs12-101:/# apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
apache2 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.23) ...
hostname: Unknown host
make-ssl-cert: Could not get FQDN, using "vs12-101".
make-ssl-cert: You may want to fix your /etc/hosts and/or DNS setup and run
make-ssl-cert: make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
make-ssl-cert: again.
/usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert: line 74: mktemp: command not found
dpkg: error processing ssl-cert (--configure):
 subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postfix:
 postfix depends on ssl-cert; however:
  Package ssl-cert is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing postfix (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of at:
 at depends on exim4 | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package exim4 is not installed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing at (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up klogd (1.5-5) ...
Stopping kernel log daemon... failed!
Starting kernel log daemon...
```

and after it stays like this forever, please help me to fix the issue.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

The critical line is probably this:

```
/usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert: line 74: mktemp: command not found
dpkg: error processing ssl-cert (--configure):
subprocess post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

That means that the configuration of ssl-cert failed because the command `mktemp` is missing. To fix, try installing the package `mktemp`. Then do

```
dpkg --configure --pending
```

to finish configuration of all unconfigured packages.

Even so, this is weird. mktemp is marked "essential" in Debian, meaning it should always be installed. Did you use some --force option to dpkg or apt-get? Something seems to be messed up on your system.

Comment: It is actually a fresh debian. the issue is , when I do "apt-get install mktemp". it still gives me "invoke-rc.d ssh restart".I am confused :(

Comment: I'm confused as well. Please post the complete console output of "apt-get install mktemp" (edit your question). Then maybe things become clearer.